# How to let users control ANY and ALL for categories using dynamic parameters?

Tags: categories, dynamic, parameters

My site has many entries, each having several categories assigned to them. Using Dynamic Parameters, I'd like to allow users to filter the entries to show only those belonging to certain categories, perhaps by selecting checkboxes. That part I know how to do.

The categories parameter in the Channel Entries tag lets you indicate that you want to show entries with ANY of the selected categories (category="2|45|4|9") or ALL the selected categories (category="3&7&8").

Is there any way to let users make the selection of ANY or ALL when they interact with the Dynamic Parameters form? So effectively, they could say either "Show me entries belonging to ANY of the categories I've selected" or "Show me entries belonging to ALL of the categories I've selected"?

Answer (score 3):

I would highly recommend using Low Search to provide the filtering you're talking about. http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#categories

By default it would show all entries, and allow you to use your categories as filters to refine your results.

It can do some pretty remarkable stuff, highly recommended!

Comment: Yeah, I figured that would be the only way. My problem is that I'm not the admin of this site, and getting authorization to install add-ons is difficult.

Comment: I hear ya, but it'll save a ton of time and the add-on vendor is a real pro. Good luck!